# How to cite and build on the work of another paper that is still under peer review?

Tags: citations, journals

I've written a paper which I submitted to journal ~5 months ago and is still in peer review. I have a follow up piece of work that is similar, but uses a different formulation of a problem (so I can show the results are similar and draw attention to the positive/negatives of using one formulation or the other).

How can I cite this in my new paper? I have published the first paper on arXiv, but it hasn't even got to the first round of reviews. I also have a need to publish as soon as possible as my Ph.D. funding runs out in 6 months - so I'd like to complete before then!

Comment: I've read many, many references to sources "to appear" in bibliographies of books. Is that not permissible in journals?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Cite your arXiv preprint**, just like you would cite any other prior work.  Peer review is not a prerequisite for something to be citeable.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is it worth noting it has been submitted? My feeling was that if I submit this paper, it may not be viewed well that it's being compared to work that hasn't yet been through peer review.

Comment: _Is it worth noting it has been submitted?_ — [shrug] Can't hurt.

Comment: I wouldn't mention that it has been submitted, because it may have been rejected and resubmitted elsewhere by the time someone reads the citation.

Comment: @user2768: Well, then? The statement "This paper has been submitted." is still true. Even if it were not resubmitted elsewhere, "This paper has been submitted." tells the reader exactly what it says - at the time of publication of the work at hand, the other paper had been submitted, but it had not yet been accepted, so what would eventually happen to that other paper is still open.

Comment: I used to write "submitted for publication" in the bibliographic entry of a paper that was, well, submitted for publication.  Eventually I realized that knowing whether the paper has been submitted is not nearly as useful as being able to see the paper, so now I much prefer to give a weblink to the paper, and when I can find one I don't write "submitted" anymore.  By the way, I also cite weblinks for things that have not been submitted, e.g. some of my own online notes.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I generally recommend against writing "submitted to X," since it might later reveal rejection by X. I also recommend against writing "under submission," since I don't find it useful. Like Pete, I favour an online version of the paper. (That's already been covered by the OP: they intend to follow JeffE's advice and cite a preprint.) That said, if you write "submitted to X" for peer-review and remove for camera-ready, then you largely avoid my concerns.

Comment: @user2768: I am not sure I see the issue with revealing rejection by X. But then, I do generally write only "under submission" (if only for brevity), because I think that information is necessary to explain why there is no more precise information about the referenced work in the bibliography - no year of publication (not yet determined), no venue (not yet confirmed), and no weblink (in my CS subfield, preprints such as arXiv are largely unheard of and accordingly unusual). Of course, either the referenced work needs to get published at some point or otherwise released "informally".

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks - this is what I have done. :) I would like them to read the previous piece!

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes, I will just state the paper has been submitted, not to where. I don't ever expect acceptance! :-)